# OData Action without a target entity

Tags: wcf-data-services, odata

Is it possible to have an OData Action that is not bound to a particular entity or instance, but rather can be invoked upon a collection?  Such as...

```
http://server:port/MyOdataService/Notifications/ClearAll
```

where Notifications is a ResourceSet, and ClearAll is an action.  I liken this to a static method in C#, somewhat.

The obvious workaround is to use a "global" action or an old ServiceOperation, but I would rather not have some of my operations scoped that high up or forced into using tedious names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the OData protocol level, it's valid to have an action parameter bound to a collection of entities. For example, if the `Notifications` entity set is made up of entities which are of type `MyNamespace.Notification`, then the binding parameter of the action will have a type of `Collection(MyNamespace.Notification)`.

Within a WCF Data Services action provider, I believe this is possible by just making the `ServiceAction.BindingParameter.ParameterType` a `CollectionResourceType` (obtained via `ResourceType.GetCollectionResourceType(/* notification type */)`). (I haven't tried this out though.)

Comment: This is correct.  Took me a minute to figure it out, but I got it working; thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I came across a solution to this earlier today.  (I don't have the issue but I found this question and recall reading the solution - why not contribute the link between the two?)

There's an example at http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/ODataActionsSample/ODataActionsSample.sln

Look at the `NonBindableActionRoutingConvention.cs` and `NonBindableActionsController.cs` files for what you need to do.

Comment: That example seems to be for WebApi.  This question is for WCF Data Services.